# How to spot jank frame in dev console?

Tags: console, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I have heard about a `Schedule Appointment` button which launches a scheduling model in Google dev tool ? I don't see it. And other console dev doesn't show more things, so I'm wondering how to hunt my jank frame (CPU time overloading a 10ms budget per frame) in my dev console please ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, as you are asking about Jank frames you are probably writing about an Android app. The console for Android app developers is now called the [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish), whereas the Google Developers Console is more for cloud development.

The Play Console will warn you about Jank in the Android Vitals section. But it won't help you debug it. For this you need to work locally on your device and in Android Studio. There is [a whole help article](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render) on different ways to do this.

The three recommended techniques are:

- [Visual inspection](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#visual-inspection), ie use your app and try to spot it. For a 10ms budget this won't work for you. You'll need one of the next two methods.
- [Systrace](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#systrace). This is probably the tool you want to use. As you use your app it lets you see where the time is going.
- [Custom performance monitoring](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#custom-monitoring). If you can't find it on a local device you might need to use [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/) to help find problems on your users devices.

Comment: I see, thanks, do you know maybe some functionalities about Jank Frame for web browser application/sites ? Like this with this awesome game : https://jakearchibald.github.io/jank-invaders/